# Jquery .insertAfter() inserts multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web app that uses jquery to inser some html on to the dom:

```
    $('<div />').html('<span class="' + someID + '-id">SomeText</span>').insertAfter($(".someidentifier"));
```

The problem I'm having is that there can be many elements with `someidentifier` class and with each of them, this code will run so as you can imagine, if I have two of them:

```
    <div class="someidentifier">Some text</div>
    <div class="someidentifier">Some text</div>
```

this code will produce the following in the dom:

```
    <div class="someidentifier">Some text</div>
         <span class="3123564654-id">SomeText</span>
         <span class="3123564654-id">SomeText</span>
    <div class="someidentifier">Some text</div>
         <span class="3123564654-id">SomeText</span>
         <span class="3123564654-id">SomeText</span>
```

where as it should be:

```
    <div class="someidentifier">Some text</div>
         <span class="3123564654-id">SomeText</span>
    <div class="someidentifier">Some text</div>
         <span class="3123564654-id">SomeText</span>
```

so I thought of using the `.next()` function and check to see if the next sibling has the class that I'm trying to output and if so cancel the insert. This is the part that I just can't figure out as I'm just saying `insertAfter(jQueryObject)` and I don't know how to intercept it and cancel it. I should note that I can't use an if statement around it because the `jQueryObject` in this case would both `div` already.

Can I modify the selector to not include the object if it has a `span` with a class of `3123564654-id` as the next sibling?

Comment: looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Adu9U/1/

Comment: The code runs twice, actually for ever instance of the divs it sees it runs. Can't really explain why as I'm under NDA but it has to be done like that unfortunately.

Comment: another words, the first time the code runs it will insert them just fine, the send time it runs, it will insert the spans again.so I'm left with 4 spans as opposed to just 2  http://jsfiddle.net/Adu9U/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the code is executed multiple times, then you can filter out `someidentifier` elements which has next elements with the new properties like

```
var someID = '3123564654';
var targets = $(".someidentifier").filter(function () {
    var $next = $(this).next();
    return !$next.length || !$next.children('span').hasClass(someID + '-id')
});
$('<div />').html('<span class="' + someID + '-id">SomeText1</span>').insertAfter(targets);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Adu9U/)

Answer (score 0):

How about checking with something like...

```
if ( $(this).has(someID).length == 0) ) 

    {
        $(this).append('whateverYouNeedToAppendHere');
    }
```